# YA Cron Question

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script called *mediacircus.py* that works when run manually (using Idle) in /home/pi. I have a Cron schedule to run it every minute that looks like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/mediacircus.py
```

but a check using

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

shows no evidence that it has run, even though another unrelated task that also runs every minute--a shell script--does run. I have ensured that the script is executable using chmod.

Using Idle, I see that /home/pi/ is a valid path.

I've tried replacing "/usr/bin/python" with simply "python", and also taken this part out completely, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does 'YA' stand for?

Comment: What is `idle`? When I use `~$ idle --version` on the command line I get: `bash: idle: command not found`.

Comment: @Ingo idle / idle3 is the 'IDE' that comes with most Python installs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE

Comment: @Dirk Ah.. not a command line ;-) Could it be that cron does not find the environment which *idle* provides?

Comment: @ahclem Does your python script run on the command line with: `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/mediacircus.py`?

Comment: Yes, it does run on the command line.

Comment: "YA" stands for "Yet Another"

Comment: @Ingo: wrt `idle`, left something for you in [The Bakery](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery)

Comment: Why do you think the problem isn't in `mediacircus.py`?  Are you sure it doesn't run?  Perhaps it fails because it needs a screen or similar resource which is not available from a cron job.

Comment: I know it works because it processes text and writes information in two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idle` is likely causing you to believe that your script is executable, when in fact it is not. You can confirm this by starting your script from the command line, just as you do in your `crontab`; i.e. type this at the command line:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/mediacircus.py
```

Also note that on Raspberry Pi, `/usr/bin/python` executes Python 2 - not Python 3.

In the event your program throws an error when run under `cron`, the following may be useful in capturing any error codes:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/mediacircus.py > ~/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

This will redirect the `stderr` output to a file in your home directory.

And you haven't revealed any of your code, so I'm forced to guess as to whether or not your .py file includes an appropriate `shebang` in the first line. Try the following:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Why? `cron` has a different set of environment variables than you do when you run as `pi`. In other words, `cron`'s $PATH is different that `pi`'s.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Seamus, it does run from the command line. The shebang looks like this: #!/usr/local/bin

Comment: @ahclem: See edited answer; it seems you've run into the diff between cron's PATH and user pi's PATH (not the same)

Comment: Thanks to all who responded; it works now. I changed the shebang to what Seamus suggested. The script gave an error so I had to use absolute addressing of the locations of files. Once that was done, it works as expected.

Comment: @ahclem: Glad you got it working. [Please read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)